# kaggle: command not found on ubuntu 18

Tags: python, pip, ubuntu-18.04, kaggle

I installed Kaggle as

> pip install kaggle

It installed successfully, but when I run

> kaggle

I get

> kaggle: command not found

Comment: Looks like the `kaggle` command is not in your path. Can you update your answer with your `PATH` environment variable? Have you checked `~/.local/bin/kaggle`?

Comment: I got     OSError: Could not find kaggle.json. Make sure it's located in /home/cc/.kaggle. Or use the environment method.